# Angular - adjust ngFor loop behavior based on values seen in loop

Tags: angular

The use case is a sequence of values to be displayed in a table.  The data is structured similar to an event stream, a single flat array of objects, containing multiple occurrences of sequences of a single header object followed by 1+ data objects.  I want to stripe the rows, with the header one color, and alternating colors for the following rows in the group.  The striping should restart after each header.

I've considered:

1. Creating a local variable to the loop where I can flag my altered concept of odd or even. AFAIK, I can't do that.
2. Use multiple tbody sections, but that would require writing unclosed tags, i.e., within the loop writing a close tbody followed by a new open tbody for the next group, which I believe isn't supported
3. Preprocessing the data to build a companion array which can be referred to via the loop index
4. Preprocessing the array to break it into an array of arrays and use nested *ngFor blocks.

Is there any simpler solution I haven't considered?

Comment: So, the only difference in the visualization is that your rows will have different colors?

Comment: Yes.  Let's say header bg is blue, odd is white and even is gray.  The sequence header data data header data data data should result in blue white gray blue white gray white

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go with a similar approach to your suggested number 4. I would use an Angular pipe which groups your objects which makes the presentation of the "rows" easier.

The grouping object could look somethinkg like this:

```
interface GroupObjects{
  header: Header,
  entries: Entry[]
}
```

The pipe would look like following:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'group' })
export class GroupPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(arr: Header | Entry): GroupObjects[] {
    const result = [];
    let group: GroupObjects = null;
    arr.forEach(entry => {
      // Check for instance or use another comparison
      if (entry instanceof Header) {
        group = { header: entry, entries: [] };
        result.push(group);
      } else {
        group.entries.push(entry);
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
}
```

And finall your HTML you could iterate over it and display your structure

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let obj of yourArray | group">
      <tr class="blueBg">Your stuff for header here</tr>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let entry of obj.entries; even as isEven">
        <tr [ngClass]="{'whiteBg': !isEven, 'grayBg': isEven}">Your stuff for the entries here</tr>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope, I haven't done a mistake in the code and this helps you :)